# Delete duplicate records without using intermediate table

Tags: sql, teradata

I'd like to delete all duplicate data from a table in a database without using a row id or an intermediate table. Is there any way to do this?

Here's my initial table:

```
emp emp_name    emp_addr
2   B   Pune1
3   C   Pune2
1   A   Pune
2   B   Pune1
3   C   Pune2
1   A   Pune
2   B   Pune1
3   C   Pune2
1   A   Pune
2   B   Pune1
1   A   Pune
1   A   Pune
```

And what it should look like with the duplicate data removed:

```
emp emp_name    emp_addr
2   B   Pune1
3   C   Pune2
1   A   Pune
```

Comment: Why would you preclude two very reasonable approaches to solving this problem?

Comment: You asked the same question which has been answered, also can you provide the query on which you are working on

Comment: Of course the best thing is to avoid duplicate rows beforehand by adding a UNIQUE constraint or simply using SET tables in Teradata :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `ROW_NUMBER`, i.e.

```
 WITH CTE AS(
   SELECT emp,
       RN = ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY emp ORDER BY emp)
   FROM employee
)
DELETE FROM CTE WHERE RN > 1
```

Thanks
Suresh

Comment: delete from cte is not allowed in Teradata

Answer (score -1):

```
delete from table where                
EmpID in(select EmpID from table group by EmpId having count(*) >1)
```

OR something like this if supported in your *RDBMS*

```
;with cte as
(
select *,rn=row_number()over(order by empID) from table
)

delete from cte where rn>1
```

Comment: This deletes all records in OP example :)